# Post copy of dynamically generated div content to new page

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, dynamically-generated

So I was researching this a bunch and thought the things I was seeing seemed a lot more complicated than what I was imagining.

I just want to take all of the HTML content within specific div in a form, including tags and ids and whatever, and copy it line for line into a new div on another page upon post submission. Some of the content is generated dynamically using javascript such as table rows and their data but that is completed before submission.

For example: take the table in the div below and post it into a div on the page the form submits to. (I am using multipart/form-data because I have a file input in this same form)

```
<form action = "example.php" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="table_container">
    <table class="example_table">
      <tr> <!--This HTML was all generated with Javascript-->
         <th>Test</th> 
         <th>Test</th>
         <th>Test</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Test</td>
         <td>Test</td>
         <td>Test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Test</td>
         <td>Test</td>
         <td>Test</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
</form>
```

I haven't tried anything yet because I haven't found anything that might do this.
A lot people mentioned the PHP include feature but I don't need an entire page and with this being dynamically generated I don't see how that would work.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated, whether it is PHP, AJAX, or JQUERY or anything.

Thanks in advance

Kevin

Comment: "Copy it onto another page" as in creating a new page / altering another page (which is only possible with server side)?

Comment: You should just make the data into an JSON object and send it with a request. Then just have a function that converts the json into html.

Comment: - code Yes, I am currently using PHP so server side is fine. - Invizi Cool. How do I do that? I have never used JSON (Im still new to programming and HTML).

Comment: I had a suggestion to convert an array of the data into JSON then store it in a hidden input value to be accessed by PHP then decoded. I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON was the way to go. I had the function that generates the table also send the data to an array

This code selects the array (references) and stringifys the data then stores it as the value of a hidden input(ref_data):

```
function input_ref_JSON() {
  var refsJSON = JSON.stringify(references);
  $('#ref_data').val(refsJSON); //write JSON data to hidden input value
}
```

then on the php page I decode it and use a recursive loop to generate a new table

```
<?php 
            $ref_JSON = $_POST['ref_data'];
            $ref_decoded = json_decode($ref_JSON);
        echo '<table>';
            foreach ($ref_decoded as $ref) {
                echo '<tr><td>'.$ref->type.'</td><td><a href="'.$ref->link.'">'.$ref->title.'</a></td><td>'.$ref->author.'</td><td>'.$ref->notes.'</td></tr>';
            }
        echo '</table>';
?>
```